# How to run the scripts without give the apk path in the setup function which is already installed in my phone using on Appium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, pytest, python-appium

Already app is installed in my phone without give the app path in setup function can i able to run the scripts in Unit-test in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run tests on the device without providing a path to the .apk location if the app is already installed on the device.

What you need to do is provide `appPackage` and `appActivity`. For example for Youtube app `appPackage` and `appActivity` could be:

```
"appPackage": "com.google.android.youtube",
"appActivity": "com.google.android.youtube.StartActivity"
```

`appPackage` is let's say technical name for the app developers need to give, while `appActivity` refers to the functionality of the app, i.e. screen you are currently on.

To find out `appPackage` and `appActivity` easy way is to open the app on your connected device (emulator or real device) and execute from Terminal/Command prompt window:

`dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’`

this will give you for example:
`com.google.android.youtube\com.google.android.youtube.StartActivity`

first part is `appPackage` and part after `\` is `appActivity`

You can find more about it in this article: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/

and here: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup/

Hope that helps.